# Sending messages through internet to app

Tags: ios6

anyone know how do I send Messages to an app, like the email app from Apple notification?
I want to notify my customer that something is ready, works like the email.
Ty

Comment: You should read about [Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use push notification.

You can follow tutorial at, 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send notification from your app, locally, you should look for [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html) official tutorial. And you need to improve your questions.